# Install library packages for other python version

Tags: python, package

I have installed the two python versions v2.7 and v3.7 on the same machine. I want to install the some packages for Python 3.7 when i am trying to install it installing for python2.7. Can any one help here how can i install the packages for python3.7.

`Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configlib-2.0.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for configlib==2.0.4
Searching for everett==0.9
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/everett/`

`[root@nodehost configlib-2.0.4]# /usr/local/lib/python3.7 setup.py install
bash: /usr/local/lib/python3.7: Is a directory
[root@nodehost configlib-2.0.4]#`

Comment: `python3.7` is a directory, is `python` inside it?

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution is to create a separate environment for different python. [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) is the way to go. It is free and it installs many everyday libraries already.

Download and install the python 3.7 version. And then create a python 2 version is simple:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

Every time you need the 2.7, just

```
conda activate py27
```

And then you can install libraries there just for 2.7, without messing up your 3.7. Vice versa for 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose your Python version with the two following commands:

```
>> python --version
Python 2.7
>> python3 --version
Python 3.7
```

If this works, just call pip like so:

```
>> python3 -m pip install everett
```